# Multiple gpu render fail: illegal adress in cuCtxSynchonize()(device_cuda_impl.cpp:2077)

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I keep getting this error when i am doing viewport cycle render.

My gpu is 3090 2080ti 1060.

<kbd>F12</kbd> render working fine but viewport render pops out that error

I was try to fix it by

- Replace GPU
- change card slot
- different order gpu
- try to plug one gpu and run it ( all card renders fine)
- try many blender version 2.79b 2.80 2.83 2.90 2.91 2.92 2.93(beta)
- non of them suddenly not working!

I remember that there was window major update and, looked up what is installed recently.

There is one update, and it called Servicing Stack 10.0.19041.925.

This window update can't be roll back once installed.

There is no way to delete this, so I can't test this that causing issue
to this Blender CUDA issue.

maybe, this is Window update issue, or Blender issue, or my GPU issue, or PCIE slot issue?

Or anyone having same kind of issue after window servicing stack update?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found out this this cause issue.

if anyone having this issue. try to off this if it on.

[image]
They are located at Window setting -> graphic setting.